# How to properly convert oracle data types to java types using JDBC?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I need to know data types of columns in a JDBC ResultSet.

I was able to get [JDBC types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Types.html), which are generated from Oracle types:

```
ResultSet rs = databaseMetaData.getColumns(null, "C##TMPUSER", null, null);
rs.next();
int code = rs.getInt(5);
String sqlJavaType = JDBCType.valueOf(code).getName();
```

which for example returns `NUMERIC` if the column in oracle is `NUMBER`.

This is the [java sql Type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Types.html), but I need the corresponding Java types, eg `String`, `int`, `float`, etc.

How I can get these data types?

Comment: Try `rs.getObject(n).getClass()`

Comment: Thanks!!! That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect the class of the object returned from [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html)'s [`getObject(i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject(int)) method:

```
Class<?> javaColumnType = rs.getObject(n).getClass();
```

which works for all column types.

Note that if the column contains a `null`, the call to `getClass()` will throw a `NullPointerException`, so you may need to guard against that.